# QScrollArea Custom Widget not Repainting Properly

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qscrollarea, qt5.6

I have a QScrollArea that contains my custom widget. When I change the data of the custom widget(which changes sizeHint() and the widget takes up more space) the end of each line and the last few lines are cut off. I've created a little program to replicate the issue.

***widget.h***

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void changeData(const QString &, const unsigned &, const unsigned &);

    QSize sizeHint() const override;
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;

private:
    QString lines;
    unsigned lineSize = 0, rowSize = 0;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    changeData("TESTING\nFUNCTIO\n1234567\nWORDS77\n", 7, 4);
    update();
}

void Widget::changeData(const QString &l, const unsigned &lineSz, const unsigned &rowSz)
{
    lines = l;
    lineSize = lineSz;
    rowSize = rowSz;
}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /*event*/)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QFont defaultFont = painter.font();
    QPen defaultPen = painter.pen();
    defaultFont.setLetterSpacing(QFont::AbsoluteSpacing, lineSize / 2 - 3);
    // set pen and font
    painter.setFont(defaultFont);
    painter.setPen(defaultPen);
    // starting point
    QPoint prntPoint(5, 15);

    for (QString::size_type ind = 0, row = 1; ind < lines.size(); ++ind)
    {
        if (lines[ind] != '\n') // if it's a letter
        {
            // print the letter and move the point to the right
            painter.drawText(prntPoint, QString(lines[ind]));
            prntPoint.setX(prntPoint.x() + 20);
        }
        else if (lines[ind] == '\n') // if the character is a newline
        {
            prntPoint.setX(5); // move point back to the very left
            prntPoint.setY(row * 20 + 15); // move down
            ++row;
        }
    }
}

QSize Widget::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(lineSize * 20, rowSize * 20);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Widget *w = new Widget;
    QScrollArea area;

    area.setWidget(w);
    area.show();

    //change string and other data variables
    w->changeData("1234567890\nQWERTYU123\nLETTERS123\nWORDSSS123\n"
                  "TESTING123\nFUNCTIO123\nLETTERS123\nWORDSSS123\n", 10, 8);

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: Widget not updating properly]

As you can see the data we set in the main function is cut off, only the first 7 characters and first 4 lines are printed, basically taking the first string we set in the constructor and taking a subset of this new string and printing it.

[image: Without QScrollArea]

Removing QScrollArea fixes the issue but I need the scrolling capabilities for my application. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: No sure but try to call updateGeometry() when you change the data and so the size hint

Comment: @Fabio That was the first thing I tried, no luck unfortunately.

Comment: I think that you have to resize it manually when the data chages, because the sizeHint it's only a recommended size that is used e.g when the item is into a layout or when the widget is shown the first time as top level widget. You can use resize(sizeHint()) or setFixedSize(sizeHint())

Comment: @Fabio waw thank you! I had thought QScrollArea would update when I called update on it(thus take the new sizeHint()) but I was wrong. Thank you!